# Selecting certain indices from numpy array and adding 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

How to add 2 to arr[0:2] and arr[5:6] so the final result is:

```
arr[3,4,3,4,5,8,7,8,9]
```

Comment: `arr[np.r_[range(2), 5, 6]] += 2`

Answer (score 2):

Note that you could create an array that has all the indices to the values that need to be modified:

```
arr[np.r_[0:2, 5:6]] += 2
print(arr)
```

---

Out:

```
array([3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 8, 9])
```

Answer (score 1):

Very straight forward :)

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

arr[0:2] += 2
arr[5:6] += 2

print(arr)
```